# Style radio buttons without span class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, radio-button

I have a HTML template coming from an XML file but the radio buttons don't have a span class in front of the label in order for me to customise this. Is there a way I can style this using angular JS. Here is an example of the code:

```
    <input type="radio" id="" value="y" name="" checked="">
    <label for="">Ja</label>
```

There is nothing we can do about the XML adding in a span class on the parse so it has to be done on our front end framework.

Comment: Why is id and name empty?

Comment: So style the `label` element instead then?

Comment: Most of the tutorials i've seen online to customize a radio button involve a span class.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the element in the CSS? Why does it need to have a span in order to be styleable?

```
input["radio"]{/* some styles */}
label{/* some styles */}
```